# Can you set both your username and real name in GIT?

Tags: git

When I log into bitbucket I can set my username, first name, and last name. Does Git have all these options or just the username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. See the list of options in [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), specifically the ones prefixed with `user.`

> **user.email**
>   Your email address to be recorded in any newly created
>   commits. Can be overridden by the GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL,
>   GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, and EMAIL environment variables. See
>   git-commit-tree[1].
>
> **user.name**
>   Your full name to be recorded in any newly created commits.
>   Can be overridden by the GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
>   environment variables. See git-commit-tree[1].
>
> **user.signingKey**
>   If git-tag[1] or git-commit[1] is not selecting the
>   key you want it to automatically when creating a signed tag or commit,
>   you can override the default selection with this variable. This option
>   is passed unchanged to gpg’s --local-user parameter, so you may
>   specify a key using any method that gpg supports.

You can only set one name.

Answer (score 3):

It has username and email.

> Tip: You don't have to use your real name--any name works. Git actually associates commits by email address; the username is only used for identification.

You can look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) for more information.